# How to return null if using SingleOrDefault() and searching a list of numbers for a number not in list?

Tags: c#, linq

When querying a list of positive numbers using `SingleOrDefault()`, how can I return null, or a custom value like -1, when a number isn't found in the list, instead of the type's default value (0 in this case)?

Comment: you cannot change the behaviour of SingleOrDefault, it will alwyays return the default of the object, in case of an int, 0, in case of int? -> null. Take one of the approaches posted below to work around it;)

Comment: @Ela I understand that. The purpose of my question was to get around that.

Answer (score 12):

You could use:

```
var first = theIntegers
                .Cast<int?>()
                .SingleOrDefault(i => i == theValue) ?? valueIfNotFound;
```

This works by casting the items to a `Nullable<int>`, then using the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)  to return the value you choose if `null` was returned (ie: not found).

Note this will throw if you have more than one matching item.  If you don't want that behavior, use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @Servy I'm assuming the OP isn't mistakenly using that instead of `FirstOrDefault` there were already some misguided answers addressing the method choice.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal My comment was direct at Reed, who said that `SingleOrDefault` would return the default value in the case of 2 items being in the list; he has since edited his answer.  I assume the OP knew what he was doing when he choose to use `Single`.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I was fixing that actually - messed up while writing it ;) (corrected now)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `DefaultIfEmpty` to specify a custom default value for an empty collection:

```
var value = numbers.Where(MyFilter)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1) //or any other default value you want
    .Single(); //OrDefault not needed; DefaultIfEmpty ensures there is an item
```

Comment: Not necessarily *any* other value. For example, **null**, will throw an exception.

Comment: @TravisJ Any value of that type.  You can't specify a value of some other type entirely, that is correct.  Oh, and if the value if not of the proper type it won't throw an exception; instead it *won't compile*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the type in your list to `int?` ( a nullable int ). The default value which you return will be 0 for an integer. For reference types it will be null. Without overloading the method you can't make the default retrurn value a custome value.

Comment: While that's true; you can modify the query as a whole (in fairly simple ways) to accomplish that goal.  It's not an impossible problem in general.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question is simplified so this does not apply, but if you are only looking for a number you already know and want to return an arbitrary number if it's not in the list, you can use the Any-Extension method:

```
int numberToLookFor = 42;
int arbitraryReturnOnNotFound = 17;

int result = numbers.Any( n => n == numberToLookFor ) ? numberToLookFor : arbitraryReturnIfNotFound;
```